# Why Or element is not working in retrieving items in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to get a specific list of items from a sharepoint list.

This is my working code (good for 2 conditions under OR element):

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
        XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
        XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");

        ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" + "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
        ndViewFields.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name=""Title"" />";

        ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Title1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Title2</Value></Eq></Or></Where>";

        try
        {
            XmlNode ndListItems = ListsService.GetListItems(sharepointList, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
            MessageBox.Show(ndListItems.OuterXml);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

However, if the queried items under the OR element exceeds 2, let's say we have 3. It will fail and returns 500 Internal Server Error.

```
ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Title1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Title2</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Title3</Value></Eq></Or></Where>";
```

I don't know where I went wrong cause if I break it down, I don't see any problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR can only ever have *exactly* two child nodes.  If you want to OR three conditions together you need to OR two of them, and then Or that node with your other condition.

```xml
<Where>
   <Or>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="Title" />
         <Value Type="Text">Title1</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Or>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Title" />
            <Value Type="Text">Title2</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Title" />
            <Value Type="Text">Title3</Value>
         </Eq>
      </Or>
   </Or>
</Where>
```

Comment: would you be able to give an example how to do it? (it would be nice to use my example ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Or>... as basis)

Comment: I got it, but this is how I implemented it.
<Where><Or><Eq><condition></Eq><Eq><condition></Eq></Or><Or><Eq><condition></Eq></Or></Where>

Answer (score 1):

CAML query can contains at most two comparison statement inside  or  block.

So in your case CAML query should be like this.

```
 <Where>
      <Or>
         <Or>
            <Eq><condition></Eq>
            <Eq><condition></Eq>
         </Or>
         <Eq><condition></Eq>
      </Or>
</Where>
```